# "So much ahead of" vs. "so much forward of"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Let's say I'm a pitcher in a baseball game, standing on the pitcher's mound which is supposed to be 100m away from the batsman. Someone messes up the mound and moves it 50 m further, making it 150 m away from the batsman.

How should I report this error if I want to ask a rhetorical question before pointing out the mistake? I want to say:

> Why is this pitching spot so much **ahead/forward** of the normal spot? It needs to be taken back 50 meters.

Is using *ahead/forward* okay? Or should I use something else?

Comment: Why is this pitching mark *further* away than it should be? It should be 50m *nearer* to the batsman.

Comment: In fact, you just used *further* yourself.

Comment: You specified *baseball*. The pitcher faces the *batter*, not the *batsman*. In cricket, the *bowler* faces the *batsman*. Also, for the record, the pitcher's back foot must be 60' 6" (~18.44 meters) away from home plate. There is no human being alive who could pitch from 50 meters, let alone 150.

Comment: @Robusto I didnt say baseball, someone edited it. I said a game because I knew I did not know the specification of distance. I just used batsman, pitcher

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you are looking in the wrong direction if the distance is further than expected. "Forward" is "towards the target"; "back" is "away from the target".

Normally one would say the spot has been placed *back* from its expected position, and needs to be moved *forward* towards the target:

> Why is this spot so far back from its normal position? It needs to be taken forward 50m.

Even if it's the batsman asking, he would still use *forward* and *back* to explain the relationship to the target, but the verb would change to indicate the motion towards him (and *this* would change to *that* of course).

> Why is that spot so far back from its normal position? It needs to be **brought** forward 50m.

---

Having got that out of the way, it's possible to address *ahead* and *forward*. Let's say the pitching spot is at 50m instead of 100m. Either word will do, but *forward* seems more natural. *Ahead* indicates a separation from the speaker and the point in question; someone standing at the right place and peering at the marked spot in the distance might use *ahead*.

> Why is the spot so far forward of the right place?
>   Why is the spot so far ahead of where it should be?

Comment: As an aside, 100m is a *very* long way to throw a ball at a batsman!

Comment: This. Since the pitcher is facing the batter, back would be the correct direction.